# Information requested regarding variant square brackets

Tags: notation, advice

This is a usage question that may or may not be relevant to mathematics.
However, as the representative to the Unicode Technical Committee for the
STIX project [*], which involved adding mathematical and technical symbols
to Unicode, I have been asked for information regarding several symbols
that were accepted as part of this effort, and require expert assistance.

The symbols in question are the square brackets with ticks, that appear
with Unicodes U+298D..U+2990:

[image: excerpt from Unicode page U_2000]

- Are these brackets used in mathematics, and if not, in what subject
  area(s) might they be used?
- Which brackets are paired?  (My inclination is that U+298D pairs with
  U+298E, and U+298F with U+2990, setting up a visual diagonal.)
- If used in mathematics, in what field(s) are they used, and with
  what meaning(s)?
- Can someone provide a published example of usage?

[*] STIX = Scientific and Technical Information eXchange 
     [history of the STIX project](http://www.ams.org/STIX) 
     [STIXfonts](http://www.stixfonts.com)

Comment: @NormalHuman -- i would gladly add a subject area tag, except that part of my question is what subject area this notation is relevant to.

Comment: My take on your three questions: 1. No. No idea. 2. And my *inclination* would have been to pair U+298D with U+2990 and U+298E with U+298F... :-) 3. Not relevant, see 1.

Comment: @Did -- Thank you for your input.  This matches one of the conjectures raised on a Unicode discussion list.

Comment: You are welcome. (And "4. No." But please do not modify your post yet again.)

Comment: Never ever seen that, but I am not an active reader of papers with exotic notations. Maybe a "you've got mail" icon by inserting an underlined/overlined V between 298D and 2990 ? (just fooling around)